# Why am I seeing an 'AttributeError' when using the Python Smartsheet SDK to create a new sheet in a folder?

Tags: python, sdk, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to use the Python SDK and API to create a new sheet in Smartsheet and was successful in installing the SDK via pip install smartsheet-python-sdk in my terminal. However, when I try to create a new sheet in a folder via the create_sheet_in_folder under the Folder object I'm not able to as that method is not showing up in my IDE, but I have folders.py saved on my device. I've verified my API key works by adding columns into a sheet but for some reason it looks like I can't really do much with creating a new sheet.

Here's my code for reference:

```
#Smartsheet API Challenge
import smartsheet

# Set your Smartsheet API access token
access_token = "ACCESS_TOKEN"
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token=access_token)

folder_id = "FOLDER_ID"
# Create a new sheet
sheet_spec = smartsheet.Smartsheet.models.Sheet({
'name' : 'Sheet B',
'columns' : [{
'title' : 'Primary Column',
'primary' : True,
'type' : 'TEXT'
}, {
'title' : 'Col 1',
'type' : 'TEXT'
}
]
})

#make the new sheet
response = smartsheet_client.models.Folder.create_sheet_in_folder(folder_id,sheet_spec)
new_sheet = response.result
```

Here's the error I get:

```
response = smartsheet_client.models.Folder.create_sheet_in_folder(folder_id,sheet_spec)

AttributeError: type object 'Folder' has no attribute 'create_sheet_in_folder'
```

Comment: At a guess, `Folder` is a class, and you're supposed to create an _instance_ of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with the code you posted.

First, the line that calls the `create_sheet_in_folder` method should be:

`response = smartsheet_client.Folders.create_sheet_in_folder(folder_id,sheet_spec)`

And second, the `type` attribute value for each column should be set to `TEXT_NUMBER` (not `TEXT`):

`'type' : 'TEXT_NUMBER'`

Make these changes and your code should successfully create the new sheet in the specified folder.

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to have solved the issue